# Astro.js <Image> component issue

Tags: image, svg, astrojs

I'm developing an application with Astro (v.4.0.8) and I encountered a problem I can't solve. I want to render the image and  imported the particular svg and also the `<Image>` component from 'astro:assets' like this:

```
---
import Image from 'astro:assets'
import './Nav.scss'
import scrollimage from '../../../images/scroll.svg'
---
```

and I use them like this :

```
 <div>
      <Image
        src={scrollimage}
        alt="asd"
        width={'30'}
        height={'30'}
        format="webp"
      />
  </div>
```

...and it doesn't work. I receive the following error on the screen

> Unable to render Image because it is undefined! Did you forget to
> import the component or is it possible there is a typo?

They use it in the same way in the docs. I keep my images in the `src/images` directory and the path to image is correct because when I cmd + click the `scrollImage` import then IDE brings me to the correct file.

Am I missing something? Any advice highly appreciated.

Comment: In SVG you are using `href` or `xlink:href` instead of `src`. Also <div> is not a valid SVG element

Comment: should be `src={scrollimage.src}` and remove `format=webp` – it's an svg after all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution for this issue. I found on one of the gitHub threads that in order to fix my issue I had to install Sharp library by running

```
yarn add sharp --ignore-engines
```

Thanks for the comments above but they did not help :( I hope my answer will help someone! :)